# Print AJAX response data (from error return)

Tags: jquery, ajax, get

I have an AJAX request script where, for whatever reason, it returns the data but also thinks the response is an error. I have contacted the creator of the API and they are looking into it, but for the time being, I'm trying to create a workaround for the response.

Here is my script:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).on('click', '#pullDetails', function() {
             $.ajax({
                type:'GET',
                url: 'https://webservices.rrts.com/TrackWebApi/api/values/'+$('input[name=proNumber]').val(),
                success: function(data) {
                    $('.errorTitle').addClass('hidden');
                    $('.errorContent').addClass('hidden');

                    $('#carrierReturnData').removeClass('hidden');
                    $('#carrierReturnData').html(Shipment.Origin.Name);
                },
                error: function(request, status, error) {
                    console.log(request);
                    console.log(status);
                    console.log(error);
                    $('#openInvoicesOverlay').html('');
                    $('#openInvoicesOverlay').removeClass('overlay');
                    $('#freightBillDetails .box-body').html(data.SearchResults[0].SearchItem);
                }
            });
        });
</script>
```

Now, the success portion doesn't work, even though data is successfully returned to my GET request. So where the "error: function..." is is where things work (even though the shouldn't).

So based on this return JSON:

[image]

How would I print the details? As in the SearchItem field that is returned. The script does work for the .html and .remove class, but the .html portion of the error:function doesn't work and it's likely because of how I am trying to print out the response data.

### Update with response

[image]

### Update with new response

> failed
>
> Object { details: "{\"SearchResults\":[{\"SearchItem\":\"****\",\"DisplayType\":0,\"Shipment\":{\"DRAvail\":false,\"ProNumber\":\"****\",\"PickupNumber\":\"Not Found\",\"CustomerNumber\":\"****\",\"BillToAccount\":\"****\",\"BillToNumber\":null,\"BOLNumber\":\"\",\"BOLReceived\":true,\"PODReceived\":false,\"PONumber\":\"SEE BELOW\",\"OrderNumber\":null,\"OperationalStatus\":null,\"Status\":null,\"InspectionAvailable\":false,\"ProDateTime\":\"2018-02-13T00:00:00\",\"DeliverDateTime\":\"0001-01-01T00:00:00\",\"SpecInst1\":\"RESIDENTIAL DELY CFA 1\",\"SpecInst2\":\"LIFTGATE DELY REQUIRED\",\"SpecInst3\":\"ANY ??'S CALL:CUST SERV\",\"TotalAmount\":\"145.38\",\"Scac\":\"COEP\",\"ReadyTimeString\":\"\",\"Pieces\":1,\"Weight\":381,\"ApptDateTime\":\"0001-01-01T00:00:00\",\"DeliveredDateTime\":\"0001-01-01T00:00:00\",\"ProjectedDeliveryDateTime\":\"2018-02-19T00:00:00\",\"HAWB\":null,\"Origin\":{\"Name\":\"ATLAS INTL\",\"Address1\":\"400 W WARNER AVE\",\"Address2\":\"\",\"City\":\"SANTA ANA\",\"State\":\"CA\",\"PostalCode\":\"92707\"},\"Consignee\":{\"Name\":\"LEANNE FRANKE\",\"Address1\":\"783 HUNTINGTON DR\",\"Address2\":\"\",\"City\":\"HIGHLANDS RANCHO\",\"State\":\"CO\",\"PostalCode\":\"80126\"},\"PickupStop\":null,\"OriginTerminal\":{\"TerminalName\":\"Commerce\"],\"AuthUser\":{\"CanViewBOL\":false,\"CanViewInvoice\":false,\"CanViewInspection\":false,\"CanViewPOD\":true,\"CanViewWI\":false,\"FBAUserID\":\"\",\"SharedSecret\":\"\",\"UserAuthenticated\":false,\"WebUser\":{\"Site\":null},\"AccountGroup\":{\"GroupCode\":null,\"MasterAccountCollection\":null},\"PermissionMask\":0,\"ManualAccount\":false}}" }

### Update

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your ajax is success, because it return json instead ajax error response, but your syntax is not correct.

```
 success: function(data) {
$('#carrierReturnData').html(Shipment.Origin.Name);
},
```

Shipment is undefined.

What you need is to get the return of success callback, which is `data`.

This means `data` == your JSON in the screenshot

```
 success: function(data) {
$('#carrierReturnData').html(data['SearchResults'][0]['Shipment']['Origin']['Name']);
},
```

**UPDATE:**

Your data is cross domain, you need working with `jsonp` instead `json`. But because you need to know where the callback first (need waiting site owners answer), so instead force doing ajax cross domain. I really prefer this way.

index.html

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
 $(function() {
         $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url: 'http://localhost/process.php',
            data: {num: $('input[name=proNumber]').val()},
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data) {
                if(data.SearchResults != undefined) console.log('success');
                else console.log('failed');
                console.log(data);
            },
            error: function(data) {
                console.log('error');
                console.log(data);
            }
        });
    });

</script>
```

process.php

```
<?php
$json = file_get_contents('https://webservices.rrts.com/TrackWebApi/api/values/'.$_POST['num']); //or you can use curl
echo $json;
?>
```

UPDATE 2:

I copy your json to json hosting service.

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<div id="carrierReturnData" ></div>
<script>
$(function(){
 $.ajax({
  url: 'https://api.jsonbin.io/b/5a8ede2aa671850974694f16/2',
  type: 'GET', 
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function(data) {
   /*
    result: 
ignore this-> AuthUser: Object { ManualAccount: false, PermissionMask: 0, UserAuthenticated: false, … }
your JSON-> details: Array [ {…} ]
ignore this-> __proto__: Object { … }

So we need to do below
   */
   if(data.details.SearchResults != undefined) {
    console.log('success');
    console.log(data.details.SearchResults[0].Shipment.Origin.Name); //result: ATLAS INTL
    $('#carrierReturnData').html(data.details.SearchResults[0].Shipment.Origin.Name);
   }else{
    console.log('failed');
    console.log(data);
   }
   
  },
  error: function(data) {
   console.log('error');
   console.log(data);
  }
 });
 
})
</script>
```

`jsonbin.io` is enabled CORS, but your target website is not allow CORS, so we need to hack this using PHP (curl or file_get_contents), which I mentioned above.

Comment: Well technically it isn't successful. The log reports "error", which is why I say it's an issue with their side. However, using your suggestion, I get "typeError: data is undefined".

Comment: I've tried your suggestion and got the new response in my question edited above.

Comment: But I should mention that the data is returned as it is above, so technically the response in successful.

Comment: Okay, that looked like it worked. I received a proper response without any type of error return. Except, the console logs "failed", but I'm wondering if that is because the output has changed. And given that the output has changed, how would I also format the success response to output one of the fields of data? Thanks!

Comment: email me your WA or telegram, hard to reply using mobile. #not in office now plonknimbuzz@gmail.com

Comment: Will do, it'll be there in a moment.

Comment: change `if(data.SearchResults != undefined) ` to `if(data.details.SearchResults != undefined)`

Comment: I've made your suggestions, but it still returns failed, then it gives the data returned and then it proceeds to say "TypeError: data.details.SearchResults is undefined. I've added a new screenshot above.

Comment: thats means you need to check data.details.SearchResults . see my lastest update. run the fiddle

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165656/discussion-between-plonknimbuzz-and-matthew).

Comment: I ended up using your suggestion but editing it to work as such: data.details.SearchResults[0].SearchItem